# Does a RHEL7 docker container use AWS hosted RHEL7 host subscription/entitlement?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, rhel7, redhat-containers

I know that Redhat containers have access to the Redhat host yum repos through hosts entitlement/subscription certificates . But this access isn't working in AWS hosted Redhat7 instance. How can i provide host yum repo access to the containers yum package manager?